# Sprout Import Doesn't Recognize Asset folderPath Property

Tags: plugin-sproutimport

I'm trying to import entries with an Asset inside a subfolder. Since I don't know what the new Craft subfolder ID will be for each Asset I tried to use the `folderPath` property from Craft's Asset element class:

```
[
{
    "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutimport\\importers\\elements\\Entry",
    "attributes": {
        "sectionId": 2,
        "typeId": 2,
        "authorId": 1,
        "slug": "my-sample-document",
        "postDate": "2017-11-09 13:06:00",
        "expiryDate": null,
        "enabled": true
    },
    "content": {
        "title": "My Sample Document",
        "fields": {
            "description": "<p>Nulla sit amet est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque ut neque.</p>"
        },
        "related": {
            "documentFile": {
                "@model": "barrelstrength\\sproutimport\\importers\\elements\\Asset",
                "params": {
                    "filename": ["my-sample-document.pdf"],
                    "volumeId": 9,
                    "folderPath": "documents/pdfs/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

However the import fails with this error:

> [error][sprout-import] Setting unknown property: craft\elements\db\AssetQuery::folderPath

I don't get an error when I use the `folderId` property. Can I only use properties that correspond with database columns? Is there any way to do this if I don't know the subfolder ID for every asset I'm importing?

- Craft 3.0.26.1
- Sprout Import 1.0.0-beta.14

Answer (score 1):

`folderPath` is not supported when relating an asset to an Entry but there is a workaround. In your generation script you can call the code below to get the `folderId` with the given path:

```
$folderId = \craft\records\VolumeFolder::find()
->where(['path' => 'documents/pdfs/'])
->scalar();
```

Comment: Where is my "generation script"?

Comment: @kgrote that is the script you created for the import json data format.

Comment: I didn't create a script. I just exported data in JSON format from ExpressionEngine and imported it to Sprout Import.

Comment: Where in the docs does it talk about how to use an import script?